# Cursor is not returning all the values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Whenever i try to fetch the row for corresponding serial no , cursor is returning all the row except that one.I might be missing something silly but not able to find out.Please help me.

```
public TimeTable getOneRecord(int dateId) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.d(TAG, "insie getOneRecord  " + dateId);
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[]{COLUUMN_ID, COLUMN_INTIME, COLUMN_OUTTIME},
            COLUUMN_ID + "-?", new String[]{String.valueOf(dateId)}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        Log.v(TAG, DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    TimeTable timeTable = new TimeTable(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUUMN_ID)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_INTIME)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_OUTTIME)));
    Log.d(TAG, " in time : " + timeTable.getInTime());
    Log.d(TAG, " Date : " + timeTable.getSerialNo());

    // close the db connection
    cursor.close();
    return timeTable;
}
```

There is total 3 record in the table and when i try to fetch the value of 2nd row, the log is showing this.

```
D/Main Activity 124: insie getOneRecord  2
Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@d643fee
    0 {
       SRNo=1
       INTime=02:08 PM
       OUTTime=null
    }
    1 {
       SRNo=3
       INTime=02:21 PM
       OUTTime=null
    }
    <<<<<
total records 3
     serial no -- 1 in time -- 02:08 PM out time -- null
     serial no -- 2 in time -- 10:23 PM out time -- 10:23 PM
     serial no -- 3 in time -- 02:21 PM out time -- null
```

Comment: Is it really `"-?"` instead of `"=?"`?

Comment: To be more direct: `COLUUMN_ID + "-?"` should be `COLUUMN_ID + "=?"`. Notice the `=` instead of the `-`.

Comment: yeah, thats what i missed. thanks